# About the simplification of Transfer Entropy formulation

Tags: probability, information-theory

everyone. I meet some problems on the simplification of the formular of Transfer Entropy and I'm not sure whether I am right.

Firstly we have 3 variables : $X=\{x_{i}\}_{i=1}^{n}, Y=\{y_{i}\}_{i=1}^{n}, X'=\{x'_{i}\}_{i=1}^{m}$. And $X$ and $Y$ are pair-wised, while $X'$ is related to $X$ (because $X$ is related to $Y$ so $X'$ is also related to $Y$).

Now assume that we have the original formulation of Transfer Entropy :
 $TE = H(Y|X') - H(Y|X',X)$

Then I tried to simplified them individually:

\begin{align}
H(Y|X') &= -\sum_{x'\in X'} \sum_{y \in Y} p(x', y)\log p(y|x') \\
&=-\sum_{y \in Y} \sum_{x'\in X'} p(x'|y)p(y)\log p(y|x') \\
&=-\sum_{y \in Y} p(y) [\sum_{x'\in X'} p(x'|y)\log p(y|x')] \\
&=-\mathbb{E}_{y\in Y} [\sum_{x'\in X'} p(x'|y)\log p(y|x')] \\
&when ~y~is~sampled,~then ~x'\in~p(x'|y),~since ~x'~is~related~to~X~and~Y\\
&=-\mathbb{E}_{y\in Y}[\mathbb{E}_{x' \sim p(x'|y)} (\log p(y|x'))]
\end{align}

\begin{align}
H(Y|X',X) &= -\sum_{x\in X} \sum_{x'\in X'} \sum_{y \in Y} p(x, x', y)\log p(y|x,x') \\
&=-\mathbb{E}_{y\in Y} [\sum_{x\in X}\sum_{x'\in X'} p(x,x'|y)\log p(y|x,x')] \\
&=-\mathbb{E}_{y\in Y} [\sum_{x\in X} p(x|y) \sum_{x'\in X'} p(x'|x,y) \log p(y|x,x')] \\
&when ~y~is~sampled,~then ~x~is~ensured,~since ~x~is~pairwith~Y\\
&=-\mathbb{E}_{y\in Y} [\mathbb{E}_{x \sim p(x|y)}[\sum_{x'\in X'} p(x'|x,y) \log p(y|x,x')]]\\
&when ~y~and~x~are~sampled,~then ~x'\in~p(x'|x,y)\\
&=-\mathbb{E}_{y\in Y} [\mathbb{E}_{x \sim p(x|y)}[\mathbb{E}_{x' \sim p(x'|x,y)} \log p(y|x,x')]]\\
\end{align}

My question is : is my simplification correct?
Thanks~

Comment: I don't know why you'd call the above simpler in any way, these are just the definitions (like, $\sum p(\cdot) f(\cdot) = \mathbb{E}[f(\cdot)]$ is trivial.). As such, yes, you've written the definitions correctly. It may be slightly more convenient to note that $H(Y|X') - H(Y|X,X') = I(X;Y|X'),$ and directly use the expression for mutual information.

Comment: Oh yes, thank you for your reply~, the reason I do this inferring is that I only can calculate $p(y|x,x')$ and $p(y|x')$. And then with the above deduction I can estimate the value of Transfer Entropy. (If the above deduction is right).